# How would I merge two database i.e one created in plain old sql server and other in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database Database named '`DatabaseEF`' and another database '`DatabaseOld`'.

The former is created in `EntityFramework` and later is a plain old database created directly in sql server.

Now we have been tasked with merging these 2 but let the old one stay the same way and should not be in `EF` context because it is also accessed by old `ado.net` drivers etc.

So how should I go about it?

Comment: There's no magical wand here, you need to painstakingly merge the schema components and figure out what works and what doesn't work, which may need change in key table columns, their relations like PK, FK. Ideally you shall ask specific questions, I have following Tables with these details, how shall i merge or use them

Comment: Those are just databases. The *client tool* used to create them doesn't matter. There's no `created in EntityFramework`. Apart from that, the question isn't clear. What does `merging these 2 but let the old one stay the same way` mean? Copy existing data to the new database? Add any missing tables/columns to the new database?

Answer (score 0):

As for the schema, scaffold (generate entities from existing database, aka. db-first) the old database, combine them into the EF context, and make some fixes if there are something not compatible with the new context or logically incorrect.
As for the existing data on production environment, apply the migration with ef and execute raw sql commands to transfer the data.